# need first table to be left justified and second table to be justified right, and below, of where the first table ends

Tags: tables, justification

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{array}{|c c c c|} 
\hline

    1000\textsuperscript{3}  & 
    100\textsuperscript{2} & 
    10\textsuperscript{1} & 1\textsuperscript{0}\\
    1000 & 100 & 10 & 1\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\textsubscript{10}\\
    \hline
\end{array}
\end{displaymath}
\caption{\label{tab:bool1}Base 10.}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{array}{|c c c c c|}
\hline

1 & x & 4  &    = &     4\\
10 & x & 3  & = &   30\\
100 & x & 2  &  = &   200 \\
1000 & x & 1 & = & 1000\\

& & & & =====\\
& & & & 1234\textsubscript{10}\\
\hline

\end{array}
\end{displaymath}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend you code sniped to complete small document with y<our table.

Comment: please make your code fragments into a complete document so that people can see the issue and test answers also add some words to the question  to make it clearer what you want. (I don't really understand the title as written). Perhaps just use `$...$` instead of the `displaymath` environment as that always centers, then use `\raggedleft` and `\raggedright`

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline,tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.75\linewidth}{R@{}L}
    $\begin{array}{|c c c c|}
        \hline
    1000^3  & 100^2 & 10^1  & 1^0   \\
    1000    & 100   & 10    & 1     \\
    1       & 2     & 3     & 4^10  \\
        \hline
    \end{array}$
\caption{Base 10.}
\label{tab:bool1}       &       \\
                        & $\begin{array}{|c c c c c c@{}|}
                            \hline
                        1       & x & 4 & = & 4         &   \\
                        10      & x & 3 & = & 30        &   \\
                        100     & x & 2 & = & 200       &   \\
                        1000    & x & 1 & = & 1000      &   \\
                            \hhline{|~~~~=~|}
                                &   &   &   & 1234_{10} &   \\
                            \hline
                        \end{array}$
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```